# Spark Kafka stream do not set kafka consumer config

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

when i try to run this code

```
Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
kafkaParams.put("group.id", "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream");
kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("topicA", "topicB");

JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
        KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                ssc,
                LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
        );


stream.mapToPair(record -> new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value()));
```

i always have the message:

```
2018-07-25 11:10:26 WARN  KafkaUtils:66 - overriding auto.offset.reset to none for executor
```

i analyze the code and notice that the method fixKafkaParams will always run.
How to solve this problem